# 'FrameProcessor' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried implementing a Deep Reinforcement Learning Network but I get the same error every time I try to run it,

```
class Atari(object):
    """Wrapper for the environment provided by gym"""
    def __init__(self, envName, no_op_steps=10, agent_history_length=4):
        self.env = gym.make(envName)
        self.process_frame = FrameProcessor()
        self.state = None
        self.last_lives = 0
        self.no_op_steps = no_op_steps
        self.agent_history_length = agent_history_length

    def reset(self, sess, evaluation=False):
        """
        Args:
            sess: A Tensorflow session object
            evaluation: A boolean saying whether the agent is evaluating or training
        Resets the environment and stacks four frames ontop of each other to
        create the first state
        """
        frame = self.env.reset()
        self.last_lives = 0
        terminal_life_lost = True # Set to true so that the agent starts
                                  # with a 'FIRE' action when evaluating
        if evaluation:
            for _ in range(random.randint(1, self.no_op_steps)):
                frame, _, _, _ = self.env.step(1) # Action 'Fire'
        processed_frame = self.process_frame(sess, frame)   # (★★★)
        self.state = np.repeat(processed_frame, self.agent_history_length, axis=2)

        return terminal_life_lost
```

The line where I am getting the error is at `processed_frame = self.process_frame(sess, frame)

```
class FrameProcessor(object):
    """Resizes and converts RGB Atari frames to grayscale"""
    def __init__(self, frame_height=84, frame_width=84):
        self.frame_height = frame_height
        self.frame_width = frame_width
        self.frame = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=[210, 160, 3], dtype=tf.uint8)
        self.processed = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(self.frame)
        self.processed = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(self.processed, 34, 0, 160, 160)
        self.processed = tf.image.resize(self.processed,
                                               [self.frame_height, self.frame_width],
                                               method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
        def __call__(self, session, frame):
            return session.run(self.processed, feed_dict={self.frame:frame})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(See my comment under OP for context)

The error message `"FrameProcessor" object is not callable` means what it says on the tin: there is an object of type "FrameProcessor", and your code is trying to *call* this object despite the fact that this object cannot be called.

(Remember that to *call* something is to treat it as a function and to try to run this function, much like how you might call a parent at a grocery store and tell them to buy you a snack.)

Where does your code try to call this `FrameProcessor` object? Well, you yourself pointed out the line:

`processed_frame = self.process_frame(sess, frame)`.

In Python, any time you write an expression of the form `something(arg1, arg2, ...)`, the Python interpreter treats the expression as a function call, which, from your error message, we know we're not allowed to do if the `something` happens to be a `FrameProcessor`.

And we know from the earlier line `self.process_frame = FrameProcessor()` that `self.process_frame` is a `FrameProcessor`. So the problem is that you're trying to call `self.process_frame` like a function when it really oughtn't be called in that way.

**So, how can this be fixed?**

Look up the documentation for `FrameProcessor`, wherever that happens to be, so that you can know how `FrameProcessors` ought to be used. With that knowledge, you can revise the lines `processed_frame = self.process_frame(sess, frame)` and maybe  `self.process_frame = FrameProcessor()` to match the intended usage, whatever that may be. At that point it's just a matter of reading and applying the relevant documentation.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the code for `FrameProcessor`, it seems the issue is caused by an extra indent before `__call__` is defined. Indents determine scope in Python, and the extra indent is causing `__call__` to be defined in the *local* scope of the `__init__` function. That means that `__call__` has no meaning outside the body of `__init__`, which is not what we want. Try removing the extra indent before `__call__` and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Well FrameProcessor is a class written by me, but I double checked the documentation and the Atari Class is written line for line like in the documentation so I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Basically, the way FrameProcessor is being used (`self.process_frame(sess, frame)`) is incompatible with the way FrameProcessor is defined. It's hard for me to say more without seeing the code for the FrameProcessor class.

Comment: I've added the FrameProcessor Class

Comment: Thanks, I think I've identified the problem (an extra indent). See my edited answer